# Flask - Openshift 500 Internal Error

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, openshift

I've been battling this issue for a while. I can't seem to get the cause. I've made sure all dependencies are in setup.py. I've ssh-ed into the app and examined the logs. I get a flask-bcrypt ImportError, but I've made sure to add it to requirements.txt.

python.log

```
[Sun Apr 12 15:02:32 2015] [error] [client 127.12.21.1]     raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
[Sun Apr 12 15:02:32 2015] [error] [client 127.12.21.1] ImportError: No module named flask.ext.bcrypt
```

postgres.log

```
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Permission denied
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  trying another address for the statistics collector
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  could not bind socket for statistics collector: Cannot assign requested address
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  disabling statistics collector for lack of working socket
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT WARNING:  autovacuum not started because of misconfiguration
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT HINT:  Enable the "track_counts" option.
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-05-21 05:07:11 GMT
2015-04-01 08:59:43 GMT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-04-01 09:31:35 GMT LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2015-04-01 09:31:35 GMT LOG:  shutting down
2015-04-01 09:31:35 GMT LOG:  database system is shut down
```

**UPDATE**
I pasted the postgres.log because of the 'database is shutdown' message I was getting.
As requested by @ydaetskcoR, here's the setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='profile',
    version='1.0',
    description='Create an Online Professional and Personal Profile',
    author='Meke Ladna',
    author_email='ladna_mekelive@yahoo.com',
    url='http://profila-meke.openshift.com/',
    install_requires=
    [
    'Flask==0.10.1',
    'Flask-Login==0.2.7',
    'Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0',
    'Flask-WTF==0.9.2',
    'Flask-Bcrypt==0.6.2',
    'alembic',
    ],
    )
```

requirements.txt

```
<pre>
alembic==0.7.6
decorator==3.4.2
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.6.2
Flask-Login==0.2.7
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-WTF==0.9.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
Mako==1.0.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
psycopg2==2.6
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-bcrypt==0.3.1
six==1.9.0
SQLAlchemy==0.9.9
SQLAlchemy-Searchable==0.9.2
SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.29.9
validators==0.7
Werkzeug==0.10.4
WTForms==2.0.2</pre>
```

Comment: Why have you posted the postgres log? That looks to be running fine and the rest of your question doesn't mention the database being an issue. More useful would have been a copy of your requirements.txt so we can see why bcrypt isn't being properly imported. Also add your setup.py

Comment: updated as requested, @ydaetskcoR

Comment: Are you sure do you have bcrypt installed in openshift? I had a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883879/openshift-python-pip-install-cffi-fails

Comment: I tried pip install while sshing. I got requirements already satisfied. I even used the --upgrade flag

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to debug the issue by using python's logging

```
<pre>
import logging
app.logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
app.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
</pre>
```

This logged the errors to my logs in openshift and as it turned out, I had my secret key not set in my environment variables.